# why nohup doesn't work in such circumstance?

Tags: java, shell

here is the content of `start.sh`:

```sh
cmd="nohup java -cp lib/*:../common/lib/* -server -Dlogback.configurationFile=cfg/logback.xml -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=30002 simulator4j.SimulateEngine --config cfg/config.pb --properties properties/  &"
$cmd
```

when I run `./start.sh`, it blocked until I input `ctrl+c`. if I directly input the cmd in terminal, it works well

Comment: Don't put commands into quotes. that's what make your `&` fail to parse as a command delimiter

Comment: @Aaron is there any solution if I do need to put it in the quote?

Comment: Why do you think you need to put it into quotes? I'm sure there are better solutions.

Comment: He wants the command as a string first, and then he wants to execute that string as a command. Quotes are allowed in this scenario.

Comment: @Titulum i'm asking the reason why he wants it as text (in order to display it maybe?) because I might be able to provide an alternative that doesn't require handling a command as a string and using `eval` to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a string in `bash` by using the `eval` command:

```sh
cmd="nohup java -cp lib/*:../common/lib/* -server -Dlogback.configurationFile=cfg/logback.xml -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=30002 simulator4j.SimulateEngine --config cfg/config.pb --properties properties/  &"
eval $cmd
```